# Apache's localhost server not updating files after saving

Tags: apache-2.4

I use Apache's localhost server for php and stuff. It was all working fine until once when I was editing my file and saving it (in Atom) to fix a mistake. But I got the same error. I clicked on that console link that took me to the sources panel (in Google Chrome) and I saw code that I wrote before I fixed the error.

At first, I thought it was Atom's problem but Notepad++ gave the exact same result. How do I fix this??

Comment: Are you running Apache on a Windows desktop PC?

Comment: @TomasPospisek Windows.

Comment: Have you checked Apache's logs? If not you might want to do that.